# Angular not working as expected in production

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, frontend, production

So, my project is working just fine in development, but i production, angular connects to socket.io just fine, but **not doing anything**. No `socket.emit` or `socket.on` none of then works.

Can you tell me why?

Heres the website: https://new.chatenium.hu

The lang is set to HU by default, but change it to english in the homapage (it forgets the selected lang after refresh, bc its not finished, its just up for testing).

I dont run the api all day for now, so let me know if its not running!

**Thanks!**

Comment: Hi. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, and from postman its works, so its an angular problem